# ADF V2 The required Blob is missing wildcard folder path and wildcard file name

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to use a wild card folder path that is being supplied by  getmetadata and foreach. The actual file name within these folders ends with _Problem_1.csv however i get the following error. can anyone advise me on where i am going wrong?

{ "errorCode": "2200", "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorSourceBlobNotExist,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The
 required Blob is missing. Folder path: client-uploads/[{\"name\":\"A001\",\"type\":\"Folder\"},{\"name\":\"A002\",\"type\":\"Folder\"},{\"name\":\"A004\",\"type\":\"Folder\"},{\"name\":\"A006\",\"type\":\"Folder\"},{\"name\":\"A623\",\"type\":\"Folder\"}]/.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
 "failureType": "UserError", "target": "Copy data1", "details": [] }

[image: fa]

Answer (score 1):

You can try having your Copy activity inside the forEach activity and having for each items dynamic expression as below, which will get the list of all Folder names (This will also include file names if any exists in the folder you are pointing in getmetadata activity).

**ForEach Activity Dynamic expression**:
Items : @activity('getFolderNames').output.childItems

[image]

**Here are child Items from getMetaData**:

```
{
"childItems": [
    {
        "name": "A001",
        "type": "Folder"
    },
    {
        "name": "A002",
        "type": "Folder"
    }
],
"effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (West US)",
"executionDuration": 0,
"durationInQueue": {
    "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
},
"billingReference": {
    "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
    "billableDuration": {
        "Managed": 0.016666666666666666
    }
}
```

Than you have to use the "item().name" in the wild card file path expression field of copy activity, to get the name of  folder per iteration of forEach activity.

In my sample, I have tried below concat expression to point to the correct folder path name for each iteration.

**Wildcard Folder path**: @{Concat('input/MultipleFolders/', item().name)}

**This will return:**

For  Iteration 1: input/MultipleFolders/A001

For  Iteration 2: input/MultipleFolders/A002

[image]

Hope this helps..

Comment: I use this pattern frequently and have formed the habit of adding a Filter activity after GetMetadata to limit the results to the expected type (like 'File' or 'Folder'). That way the ForEach is acting only over the type of item that I intend.